# Wave Equation Partial Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Basically I got a simple wave equation with an extra twist. The PDE is $$\frac {\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = c^2\frac {\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} + L$$ with homogeneous boundary condition. As usual, I use the ansatz $ Y(x,t) = F(x)G(t) $ and I have $\frac {\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} =F''G $ and $\frac {\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} =FG''$. I substitute this in, and now I have $$FG''= c^2F''G +L$$
I don't know how to make this separable--obviously if I divide both sides with $FG$ as usual, then I will have that annoying constant $\frac {L}{FG} $ and I don't know how to make it separable then.

Can anybody help me? I know I have to separate it somehow, but I don't know exactly how to.

{The actual problem is an inhomogeneous boundary condition type of problem, but I have found the steady state solution, so I just have to find the transient solution, thus the homogeneous boundary condition}

---

The actual question:

- PDE: $$\frac {\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = c^2\frac {\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} + L,\quad 0 \leq x \leq J,\quad t>0$$ 
  where $L$ is constant and $c$ is constant wave speed.
- Boundary Condition: 
  $ u(0,t)=0$, $t>0$ and $u(J,t)=h$, $t>0$
- Initial Condition: 
  $u(x,0) = 0$, $0<x<J$ and $\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} (x,0)=0$, $0<x<J$

I did the steady state solution bit, and got it as $w(x)= \frac{-Lx^2}{c} + \frac {Hx}{L} +\frac{GLx}{c} $. So I modified the boundary condition and initial condition to get the transient part, and I got the boundary condition homogeneous. However when I try to solve it, the question above arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y(x,t) = w(x,t) + \phi(x)$ where $\phi(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$. From this it is seen that $\phi'(x) = 2 a x + b$, $\phi''(x) = 2a$ and
\begin{align}
\partial_{t}^{2} w = c^2 \, \partial_{x}^{2} w + 2a c^2 + L.
\end{align}
In order to cancel the $L$ term let $2 a c^2 + L = 0$ which leads to
\begin{align}
\phi(x) = - \frac{L \, x^{2}}{2 \, c^{2}} + b \, x + c_{1}.
\end{align}
Now it is understood that the transformation
\begin{align}
y(x,t) = w(x,t) - \frac{L \, x^{2}}{2 \, c^{2}} + b \, x + c_{1}
\end{align}
will make the p.d.e more solvable without "complications".

---

How this applies to the original problem is the following:
\begin{align}
u_{tt}  = c^{2} u_{xx} + L \hspace{5mm} u(0,t) = 0 , \, u(a,t) = h\\
u(x,0) = 0, \, u_{t}(x,0)= 0
\end{align}
The solution form proposed is
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = w(x,t) - \frac{L \, x^{2}}{2 \, c^{2}} + b \, x + c_{1}
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
u(0,t) &= 0 = w(0,t) + c_{1} \\
u(a,t) &= h = w(a,t) - \frac{L \, a^{2}}{2 \, c^{2}} + b a + c_{1} \\
u(x,0) &= 0 = w(x,0) - \frac{L \, x(x-a)}{2 \, c^{2}} + \frac{h \, x}{a} = w(x,0) - \phi_{1}(x) \\
u_{t}(x,0) &= 0 = w_{t}(x,0)
\end{align}
From the first equation it is seen that $w(0,t) = 0$ and $c_{1} = 0$. From the second let $w(a,t) = 0$ to obtain
\begin{align}
b = \frac{h}{a} + \frac{L \, a}{2 \, c^{2}}.
\end{align}
From all of this it can now be said that the original differential set is transformed by
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= w(x,t) - \frac{L \, x(x-a)}{2 \, c^{2}} + \frac{h \, x}{a} 
\end{align}
into
\begin{align}
w_{tt} = c^{2} w_{xx}  \hspace{5mm} w(0,t) = w(a,t) = 0 , w(x,0) = \phi_{1}(x), w_{t}(x,0) = 0
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\phi_{1}(x) = \frac{L \, x(x-a)}{2 \, c^{2}} - \frac{h \, x}{a}.
\end{align}
The equation for $w(x,t)$ is then an easier equation to solve. Since the boundaries for $x$ are zero at each end it suggests a sine solution and can be stated as
\begin{align}
w(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( A_{n} \cos\left( \frac{n \pi c t}{a} \right) + B_{n} \sin\left( \frac{n \pi c t}{a} \right) \right) \, \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right)
\end{align}

Note: the boundary conditions $w(x,0) = w_{t}(x,0) = 0$ leads to $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ being zero. This suggests that $w_{t}(x,0) \neq 0$.

---

Returning to the original form the solution is of the form
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \frac{h \, x}{a} - \frac{L \, x(x-a)}{2 \, c^{2}} +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( A_{n} \cos\left( \frac{n \pi c t}{a} \right) + B_{n} \sin\left( \frac{n \pi c t}{a} \right) \right) \, \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: I'm very lost. So with the ϕ(x) known, do we just essentially do the w(x,t) part of the pde? Do we just ignore the L constant and then just plugging in it back once we got into the solution?

Comment: @user234395 yes. Since the p.d.e. depends on $x$ and $t$ the remaining $w(x,t)$ would satisfy $w_{tt} = c^2 w_{xx}$.

Comment: So, when we do the w(x,t) pde part, does the boundary condition changes? I do kind of understand your method, but it is still quite fuzzy to me. Thanks a lot for your help by the way!

Comment: Or does the boundary condition changes--like do we subtract the 0 boundary condition with ϕ(0)=c? If it is, then it would be pretty complicated wouldn't it? I would have to do the steady state again and things like that? And also does the initial condition changes?

Comment: @Skipe edit the question/problem to include the boundary conditions of the problem and I'll use them to show how to utilize them.

Comment: Edited it! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Oh, turns out after I do the steady state solution the constant goes away? And I noticed that the steady state solution is similar to our ϕ(x). Is that right?

Comment: @Skipe yes, the L term would be removed and the steady state is $\phi(x)$.

Comment: @Skipe The remaining work has been added.

Comment: @Leucippus why is w (x,0) = 0? I thought it would be equal to -ϕ(x)? Because u (x,0)=0 and u (x,0)=w(x,0)+ϕ(x) = 0 So w(x,0)= -ϕ(x) Which equals Lx(x−a)/2c^2 - hx/?

Comment: she is actually right. why do you put your initial condition  w(x,0) = 0? Isn't it supposed to be w(x,0)= -ϕ(x)?

Comment: @tecmath  yes, nice find and fix.     Skipe: an amendment has been made.